# Insert string variable into datagridview.Columns[] where string or int required. C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

It has been many years since I last asked a question on here so I hope I can get some help on this..

```
foreach (object listItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
dataGridView1.Columns[].Visible = true;
}
```

I would like to insert listItem into the []. I can see that it will work with:

```
["name"]
[1]
```

But I need something like
`["{0}", listItem]` But I cant get it to accept what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not understanding - you want to insert a listitem corresponding to the name of any checkbox checked? dataGridView1.Columns[listItem.ID].Visible = true; or listItem.Name or listItem.Value or listItem.Text

Comment: Yes, listItem returns the name of the checked boxes. Brainwave* If i change listItem to a string from an object... That should get what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to make various columns in a datagrid visible based on an item selected in a checkboxlist?

Comment: Yes. I have series of check boxes in checkedListBox1. The foreach statement determines which are checked by returning the listItem name of each checked items. From that I wish to make the corresponding column in a datagridview visible or not.

Comment: If the column is named the same as the checkbox, use my suggestions above for the corresponding part of the checkbox that matches the column name (either Name, ID, Value, or Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `checkedListBox1` is a `checkboxlist`, then doing a foreach on the checked items will mean `listItem` will be a check box, not a string. You will need to do something like:

```
foreach (object listItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[listItem.Name].Visible = true;
}
```

Please see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details on the [CheckedItems property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding my comment.

Comment: Yes the problem was caused by having listItem set as an object. Changing it to a string and having the column names in the datagridview and the names of the checkboxes equal to each other fixes this. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user3450018 - note that the CheckedItems property returns the items that are checked AND indeterminate. You might want to do a check on the item's check state first.